# How to update Perforce client tool for the command line on Linux

Tags: perforce

How can I update the Perforce client tool for the command line on my Linux machine?

My goal is to have the current/latest version.
I found a method to uninstall and re-install p4 "***How to uninstall/reinstall helix-p4d under ubuntu/debian***"; however, it is not working out.
This is the link :

http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2017-April/073405.html

problem occurred from step 1. In step 1 it states to remove *service-name.conf* from /etc/perforce/p4dctl.conf.d/ BUT this location does not exist on my machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the download page, download the new executable, and save it over your existing one.  Note that `p4d` is the server, not the client!  You want `p4`.

https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4

Comment: Done. Is there a way to check the version to confirm its the latest?

Comment: `p4 -V` prints the client version info.

Comment: Yes, its now using "Rev. P4/LINUX26X86_64/2019.2/1885864 (2019/11/18)." The current rev. Thanks a-lot.